# Exception in cleaner thread when reading files from S3 in local Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

Following is in my class-path:

- aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
- hadoop-aws-2.7.3.jar
- spark-sql-2.2.0.jar

Following code works fine:

```
object MySparkJob {
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MySparkTest").setMaster("local[4]")
    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
    ......all credentials config stuff here.......
    val input = spark.textFile("s3a://mybucket/access_2017-10-30.log_10.0.0.176.gz")
    val pageStats = input filter(_.contains("pagestat"))
    val parsedRecords = pageStats flatMap accessLogRecordToCaseClass
    val evIDs = parsedRecords map (_.evid)
    println("Size is " + evIDs.collect().toSet.size)
    spark.stop
  }
}
```

I run the job with `sbt clean compile run`.

But in the console I see following warning with the exception wrapped:

```
17/11/10 15:22:28 WARN FileSystem: exception in the cleaner thread but it will continue to run
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Statistics$StatisticsDataReferenceCleaner.run(FileSystem.java:3063)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Though this is a warning I still would like to understand why it happens. Probably some of you encountered similar thing in the past and can advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry; it's just a cleanup tread being told to stop in application shutdown. HADOOP-12829 explicitly toned down the warning message when interrupted to ""Cleaner thread interrupted, will stop"

Comment: I see. Thankn you.

Comment: don't be afraid to look at the source code; its what I did to work out that: follow the stack trace, select it and say "show git revision history for selection". The list of changes which come usually show whether a problem is fixed in latest versions, or at least what the problems were